# mysql could not join tables on name if name has underscore

Tags: mysql, join

How can I join two tables on the name, while they have underscore?
For example:

```
SELECT       *
FROM        table1
INNER JOIN  table2
ON          table1.stringColumn = table2.stringColumn
WHERE       table1.stringColumn!= '';
```

This doesn't work if table1.stringColumn= test12_42 and table2.stringColumn= test12_42.

How can I join them, altought the names have umlaute and underscores?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to replace the underscores before the join? does this work without the REPLACE() in there?

Comment: Why are you replacing underscores with spaces? Whatever it is you're doing doesn't make any sense

Comment: wrap the names in backticks.

Comment: use the backticks

Comment: also if I don't use replace it is not working

Comment: You should join attributes of different tables together, not the tables themselves ("joining" the tables is closer to a UNION operation). It doesn't make any sense to do what you're talking about.  Can you provide some additional context regarding what you hope to accomplish (for example, the schema of both tables and any dependencies they share)?

Comment: I think your terminology is confusing the audience here.  (It sounds like you're talking about the actual *table name*, not a string column which just happens to be *called* "name".)  Can you provide sample data for this query, the expected output, and the actual output?

Comment: maybe name was a bad example to show what I want to do... I actually want to join two tables on a column which is named name.. both tables have this colum which contains strings..

Comment: Can't you just do a join on the name (without any replacing) and do a replace in the select field? In don't see the profit of doing a replace in the join.

Comment: now i have edited the post... the main problem is that I can't join all entries if the string contain a underscore..

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the space and you have it.

```
SELECT       *
 FROM        table1
 INNER JOIN  table2
 ON          REPLACE(table1.name, '_', '') LIKE REPLACE(table2.name, '_', '')
 WHERE       table1.name != '';
```

If your reason is that you do not care for the existence of _ in any of you table column or similar reason.

Comment: I have tested it on my mysql, works perfectly, I suggested you replace space ' ' with no space '' @alex

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks:

- If you do the same operations on both the fields, it is useless as that has no effect on the result. Do the replacement in the select statement.

  SELECT REPLACE(table1.name, '_', '')
  FROM table1
  INNER JOIN  table2
  ON table1.name = table2.name AND table1.name != ''
- It is not useful to use like in join if you don't use the % sign. Use the '=' sign.

  SELECT *
  FROM table1
  INNER JOIN  table2
  ON REPLACE(table1.name, '*', '') LIKE CONCAT('%',REPLACE(table2.name, '*', ''), '%') AND table1.name != ''